# How many ways can $5$ rings be placed on $4$ fingers?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been trying to solve this problem and I am kind of struggling with it and with other combinatorics problems. Could you check and see if i did it right?

Given problem:

> 1. How many ways can 5 rings be placed 4 fingers if the rings are all the same?
> 2. What if the rings are all distinct?

Answer:

1. I used the formula $\tbinom{n+k-1} k$ because I assumed that the question is saying that order doesn't matter and repetition is allowed; therefore I',m using that formula. By using that formula I have come up with this:  $\tbinom{5+4-1}4 = \tbinom 8 4=\tfrac {8!}{4!(8-4)!}$
2. Since the rings are distinct (meaning different), i used $n^k$ to compute it: $5^4$

Could anyone check if I did it right or wrong? If wrong, could you correct it and tell me how to solve it correctly? Because I really want to understand what I did wrong and know how to solve it correctly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Excellent showing your work! Regards

Comment: Please learn to use your shift key. It will go a long way toward convincing people to spend their valuable time helping you if you show you're not too lazy to capitalize.

Comment: Where are these formulae coming from? Can you give an intuitive explanation of why they apply?

Comment: did i do it right? am i on the right track??

Comment: If you thing there are $\tbinom{n+k-1}k$ ways to put a total of exactly $n$ rings on $k$ fingers, then you are wrong. For $k=1$, this yields $n$, which is wrong.

Comment: then could you correct me? please

Comment: Actually your answer to the second problem was wrong. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: what about first problem? wasnt i right?? and for b) how would you computate it?

Comment: can anyone help??? im really confused now

Comment: I think the reason no one has helped is that your questions are missing a lot of details. Can you put more than one ring on each finger? Do all of the rings have to be used up, or can you decide not to wear some of the rings?

Comment: (also I believe re-posts are frowned upon)

Comment: possible duplicate of [counting more problem continue](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422224/counting-more-problem-continue)

Comment: Hello again, amie/jake/tyler/ammie.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, if you are assuming all five rings are worn, you're close; you just mixed up your $n=4$ and $k= 5$. For the first: we can look at this as the number of ways to sum 4 non-negative integers to equal $5$: 
$$\underbrace{f_1 + f_2 + f_3 + f_4}_{n = 4\;\text{fingers}} = \underbrace{5}_{5\; \text{rings}}$$ where the $f$'s stand for fingers (four of them), and the 5 is the number of rings. This gives us: $$\binom{4 + 5 -1}{5} = \binom{8}{5} = \dfrac{8!}{5!3!} = \dfrac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{3\cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 56\;\;\text{combinations}$$

In the second case, there is no assumptions being made by your method: counting every possible way of wearing no ring, one ring...5 rings, on any one or more fingers gives us $5^4$ ways of wearing distinct rings, or no ring at all.

If you want to require that all rings be worn, as in case one, then we multiply the result of $(1)$ by $k! = 5!$, which gives all permutations of the rings, as they are distinct, and can thus be rearranged: that gives us $$(5!)\binom{4 + 5 -1}{5} = (5!)\binom{8}{5} = (5!)\dfrac{8!}{5!3!} = (5!)\dfrac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{3\cdot 2 \cdot 1} = (5!)56\;\;$$

Comment: @ammie Does this help you?

Comment: + Looks to me too like @Amzoti.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the classic stars and bars problem, and your formula is wrong.

You need to put 5 rings on 4 fingers. So consider a string of 5 R's and 3 bars, giving you such a picture. E.g. `RRR||R|R` says put $(3,0,1,1)$ rings on fingers $(1,2,3,4)$. It's easy to convince yourself there is an exact correspondence between such strings and arrangements that you are seeking. So it's enough to count the number of such strings.

But in such a string, there are $n=5$ places for `R` and $k-1=3$ places for bars, and picking either all stars or all bars should be enough (because all other places will be filled by the other symbol). Since there is a total of $n+k-1 = 8$ positions, there is a total of
$$
\binom{n+k-1}{n} = \binom{8}{5} = \frac{8!}{5!\cdot 3!} = 56
$$
such strings.

Alternatively, picking bars, you get
$$
\binom{n+k-1}{k-1} = \binom{8}{3} = \frac{8!}{5!\cdot 3!} = 56
$$

as well.

Comment: Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

By the stars-and-bars approach, the solution for part 1 is $n+k-1\choose n$.
For the second part note that different ring orders *per finger* may produce different outcomes. This is accounted for by simply multiplying the part 1 result with $n!$ (write down that stras-and-bars again and note that the stars can be permuted arbitrarily.

---

The number $\lim_{n\to\infty} n!{n+k-1\choose k}$ might be called Liberace constant.

Comment: You're using $n$ and $k$ interchangebly here. Look at the difference between your two binomials.

Comment: Huh. I didn't realize different orders on one finger were to be considered different. Silly me.

Comment: Shouldn't this goes to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

Without creating much confusion or providing formula,I would say just consider that the ring can be placed in either of the 4 fingers(as your original Q does not tell the nature of the rings,the next part of it has asked for identical and different rings,I am answering for the original).Now the 2nd one can be again placed in the same finger or other 3 remaining fingers and 3rd ring can again go into the same finger or again in any of the 3 remaining fingers and so forth.Now just all the combination will be met(be it 1,1,1,2/0,0,3,2....)as of now every ring is considered of its chance of falling into any 1 of the fingers in 4 ways i.e; the highest and the lowest chances both are met.
4^5.
This means every ring has 4 ways of falling into a finger(here Q is for 4 fingers)  be it any combination with other rings.It has to fall into any 1 of the 4 fingers. 
So, the answer is 4^5 in this case.My answer is correct and how do I know this?..Well it was one of the questions in my competitive exams & if I am wrong I will re-check it once and come back to edit this comment.
My ans is also for those who have problem understanding formulae buy theoretically it can be understood by all.Understanding the arrangement is a problem such is the case in this one but in case of rings just consider its highest arrangement as it includes every other combination depending on the questions.