# counting more problem continue

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

i have asked but no one was able to help so i am re-posting, hoping someone can help me. i did the computation and i could be wrong but i have provided my answer.

Given problem:

1. How many ways can 5 rings be placed 4 fingers if the rings are all the same?
2. What if the rings are all distinct?

Answer:

1. I used the formula $\tbinom{n+k-1} k$ because I assumed that the question is saying that order doesn't matter and repetition is allowed; therefore I',m using that formula. By using that formula I have come up with this:  $\tbinom{5+4-1}4 = \tbinom 8 4=\tfrac {8!}{4!(8-4)!}$
2. Since the rings are distinct (meaning different), i used $n^k$ to compute it: $5^4$

Comment: As all the answers are here, it's unfortunate that this copy is the one marked as a duplicate.