# Combinatorics how many combinations of 5 rings can be swapped on 4 fingers

Tags: combinatorics

I have been trying to study combinatorics online to help me with my general understanding however i am unable to follow a part of one of the steps i see commonly, both in a textbook question and just for a reference I'm using one on stackexchange.

If there are $5$ rings that are all different, and they can be placed upon $4$ fingers, and all have to be worn the formula given was:

\begin{equation}
\binom{4 + 5 - 1}{5} = \binom{8}{5} = \frac{8!}{5!\,3!} = \frac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{3\cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 56
\end{equation}

I fail to follow the logic past the second step. Where does $3$ factorial come from. And why if it is notated as $5! \cdot 3!$ is the resulting next step notated as only $3\cdot2\cdot1$.

The full question im paraphrasing from is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422136/how-many-ways-can-5-rings-be-placed-on-4-fingers)

Comment: I am confused, can all five rings go on one finger? Or does each of the four fingers get exactly one ring?

Comment: If 2 rings are on one finger, and the other 3 fingers each have one ring, does the order that the rings appear on the finger with 2 rings matter?

Comment: Most times i encounter this question in textbooks it just asks the number of ways you can arrange all the rings on the number of fingers. I dont think iv ever had it specify this before.....you make a very valid point....i went on the assumption the questions meant "you have to arrange the rings in any way possible, but atleast 1 ring per finger.." however im unsure....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second step is by the definition of binomial coefficient:
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{matrix}
n\\
m
\end{matrix}\right) = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}
\end{equation}
The third one is because of the following equality:
\begin{equation}
\frac{8!}{5!} = \frac{8·7·\dots·1}{5·4·\dots·1} = 8·7·6
\end{equation}